# javascript indexOf with JSON stringified objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find out if a string exists like so:

```
var test1 = '{"packageId":"1","machineId":"1","operationType":"Download"},{"packageId":"2","machineId":"2","operationType":"Download"}';

alert("found: " + test1.indexOf('{"packageId":"1","machineId":"1","operationType":"Download"}', 0));
```

However, the result is always 0.

what gives?

Comment: 0 is the index (place) of text that you were searching

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just in case this isn't a joke...

`String.prototype.indexOf` returns the occurence of a matching string within a target string, since you just look for the very first occurence of that line, it correctly returns zero.

If you modify your search-string (for example with some random letters), you will get `-1` as result since it will not get found.

There is a practice using the *binary not* operator, to pretty much bring the result from `.indexOf()` down to a boolean expression. This would look like

```
var res = test1.indexOf('{"packageId":"1","machineId":"1","operationType":"Download"}');

if( ~res ) {
   // we have a match
} else {
   // no match at all
}
```

Without going into great detail, the *not*-operator will negate each bit from a byte, also the *extra bit* which is used to determine if the value is positive or negative. So, since in ECMAscript only very few values are evaluated to *falsy values*, negative values will evaluate to `true`.

To really have a boolean result, it would look like

```
if( !!~res ) { }
```

which again is not really neccessary in this case.

The far more often used practice to get the "right" result using `.indexOf()` (same goes for Arrays), is to check if the result is greater than `-1`

```
if( res > -1 ) { }
```

Comment: so how would i find out if a string/or part of a string exists?

Answer (score 0):

ya its correct indexOf will return starting index of the string you mention, thats y its gives 0. If string is not exist it return -1

Some sample example 
    var sample= "welcome to javascript";

```
alert ( sample.indexOf("welcome",0)); // return 0

alert ( sample.indexOf("come",0)); // return 3

alert ( sample.indexOf("came",0)); // return -1

alert ( sample.indexOf("javascript",0)); // return 11
```

Match :

```
if(sample.indexOf("welcome",0)>-1)
    alert("match");
else
    alert("Not match")l
```